# Install android app to a specific user on the emulator or a device in vscode during debug run?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Flutter app and I test it on a physical android device. I have work profile enabled on it. [By default](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#testing_tips) `flutter run` in debug mode installs the app to both current and work profile. If I uninstall the app from the current profile and try to debug run a fresh build, it fails installing or stalls on the "installing app" phase. The app in the work profile conflicts and prevents the new installation to both users.

The build installs successfully once the app from the work profile is also uninstalled. So, I want to specifically install the app to the current user and not any other users on the device possibly by specifying arguments in the Visual Studio Code as I want to see logs in the debug console and not in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by editing VSCode's launch configuration and passing user id in the arguments as `--device-user=<id>`.

In the flutter-project/.vscode folder, edit the launch.json file. Add `"args":["--device-user=0"],` line as shown below.

```json
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "app-name",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["--device-user=0"]
        },
```

Get the user ids by executing `adb shell pm list users` in a terminal when the device is connected.